# Jquery Remove top 2 columns from each row in a table

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML table with a 'Send Email' button at the bottom.  When that button is clicked I want to get the HTML for the table and do an AJAX post to send it in an email through PHP.  However, I want to remove the first 2 columns from the table as they contain controls that are not needed in the email body.

Here is my jQuery for the button click:

```
 $(document).on('click','#EmailClick',function(e) {

    $("#myTable tr").each(function() {
        $(this).filter("td:eq(1)").remove();
        $(this).filter("td:eq(2)").remove();
    });
    var TableHTML = $('#myTable').html();
    $.post("AJAX/SendMail.php", { EmailBody: TableHTML })
        .done(function(data) {

    })
        .fail( function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    });
 });
```

The email gets sent successfully, but it is not remove the first 2 columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vrdW5/)***

Use [.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) - MDN

```
$("#myTable tr").each(function() {
    $(this).find('td').slice(0,2).remove();
});
```

The syntax explanation : `.slice(starting_Index, number_of_elements_toremove)`

The above will select the first 2 columns (i.e.; index 0 & 1) and then removes them from the DOM.

Comment: @oGeez answer worked as well but I went with this one.  I also had to add an additinal line: $(this).find('th').slice(0,2).remove();  to get rid of the header in those first 2 columns.  THANKS!

Comment: @Nate23VT - great. glad to help. please upvote all helpful answers too.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code

```
$("#myTable tr").each(function() {
  $(this).find('td:eq(0), td:eq(1)').remove();
});
```